# Deformed Arabic JSON response text with laravel setStatusCode

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5.4, arabic

I use `setStatusCode` like the following in the controller's action:

```
return (new \Illuminate\Http\Response)->setStatusCode(422, __('Required unique integer. We suggest :val',['val' => count($titlesList)+1]));
```

The returned message is translated and it received well using AJAX while using English interface of the app. but when turn into Arabic the message text is deformed like shown in the screen shot:

[image]

I don't know how to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in such context because I think that issue is due to it. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: have you checked your html is set to unicode
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

Comment: Yes sure it is @Marcus